# navigate to another page after Thread sleep in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am making an splash screen page. That will show on start up of application. I set the thread sleep in it. But i am unable to navigate it to another main page of application. I set the splashscreen page at loading time. It is also showing when app is loaded. But the problem is that i am not able to navigate it.

here is my code.

```
public partial class WindowsPhoneControl1 : UserControl
{
    public WindowsPhoneControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));        
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you open the braces after Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: was trying in this method. Because without braces it also giving error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: an object reference is required for the non static field, Methods or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(system.uri)'

Comment: You should do that in the `OnNavigatedTo` event of the parent page, rather than in the UserControl's constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the PhoneApplicationFrame if you're navigating from a user control.

```
  var myPage = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
  myPage.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

However, I don't think this is the best way to do the splash screen. For a number of reasons, not least that it's actually not doing anything useful while you're waiting.

For a basic splashscreen, you have an image overlayed over the content of MainPage.xaml, and use a DispatcherTimer to collapse the visibility of the image after a set period of time. This would allow you to do any required setup while the splash screen is displaying, and then hide the splashscreen once the setup is complete or the time elapses.

Here's a decent tutorial

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications